# Visual Studio Vs Visual Web Developer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, ide, visual-web-developer

I am trying to write a web application using **ASP.NET MVC**. I prefer **C#** as the programming language.

Which IDE is better to use for this purpose? **Visual Studio** or **Visual Web Developer**?

What are the features of the IDEs? What are the benefits of using one over the other?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I understand, [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) (VWD) is simply a free version of the [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/default.mspx) components necessary to develop web based solutions.

[Here is a list of features missing from VWD](http://blogs.msdn.com/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2006/06/26/647516.aspx) that you get in a Professional edition of Visual Studio 2008 (VS2008). In short, VWD Express 2005

> 1. is **Not Extensibile** with other add-ons or third party tools
> 2. **Only supports Web site projects (2005).** You cannot add a Class
>    Library project or a Web Controls
>    Library project to the solution.
>
> **UPDATED - VWD 2008 SP1 also allows Web Application and Class Library Projects in the solution**.
>
> 3. **Lacks** the ability to combine **Source Code Control**
> 4. has **no Accessibility checker**
> 5. **Lacks** ability for **automatic generation of resources for
>    localization**
> 6. **Cannot attach debugger to a process**
> 7. has **no Native code debugging**

The obvious advantage of VWD over VS2008 is that it is free and if you can work smart with it given the missing features, it may be the more pragmatic option for you. If those are features that you can't live without, VS2008 may be a wise investment - you also get all of the features missing from other Express products (Visual Basic 2008, Visual C# 2008, etc).

Take a look at [MSDN's comparison chart for Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa700921.aspx). I can't find 2008's but would suspect it to be very similar.

Comment: All of point 2 is now wrong. As of Visual Web Developer 2008 SP1, you can now have Web Application Projects, and indeed raw class library projects in the solution - this is so you can build projects using ASP.NET MVC in it.

Comment: I've also previously successfully created Web Controls library projects in Visual C# Express 2005 and used the resultant dll in VWD - you need to declare the libaray in the web.config of the website to get VWD to recognise it.

Comment: Thanks Zhaph, will update. The points are for VWD Express 2005

Comment: Visual Web Developer is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio will allow you to integerate with Source control and attached debugging to IIS processes.

As a lone developer knocking up some pure ASP.NET-MVC application then Web Developer would do, for serious work you really need studio.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also lack the ability to publish a site without visual studio, you can certainly run a website, but it won't build the binaries for release, with web developer you have to publish the source to iis.

Comment: Again, wrong as far as VWD 2008 SP1 is concerned - this has the ability to create Web Applications, and thus a compiled binary. This was added to support ASP.NET MVC development on the platform.

Comment: Again?.. Regardless, that is fantastic, the last time I used an VWD was 05 and obviously you weren't able to compile.  Good to know they added it to 08.