# Small but nice differences between VS 2010 Professional and Web Developer Express 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-web-developer-2010

I have found similar posts to this one, such as;

- [Visual Studio Vs Visual Web Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542359/visual-studio-vs-visual-web-developer),
- [What are the limitations of Visual Web Developer Express 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088756/what-are-the-limitations-of-visual-web-developer-express-2010)
- [What are the differences between visual studio and VS express edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741447/what-are-the-differences-between-visual-studio-and-vs-express-edition)

But I have a encountered a selection of minor differences such as in VWD it's not possible to make conditional breakpoints and you can not hit Ctrl+comma to launch the very time-saving Navigate to-dialog. What more diffences like these are there? It seems impossible to find a comprehensive list of these... Please note that it is the 2010 editions I'm interested in to compare.